# Как сделать, чтобы содержимое блока вышло за его нижнюю границу?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать, чтобы при наведении содержимое блока появлялось и выходило за его нижнюю границу, перекрывая ее, ***НО ВНИМАНИЕ!*** не двигая текст под блоком, а все остальные границы блока вообще исчезали? Обязательно, чтобы текст под блоком не отодвигался вниз, а оставался на месте, где был изначально.

> Желательно без js

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul style="display:none;width:100%;height:200%">
    <li>Один</li>
    <li>Два</li>
    <li>Три</li>
    <li>Четыре</li>
    <li>Пять</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1 style="margin-top:20px">Заголок не двигать</h1>
```

Comment: Если честно, не понял о чем речь....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.content {
  border: 3px solid #fa0;
  position: relative;
  height: 1em;
}
.content:hover {
  border: 3px solid transparent;
}

.content ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
.content:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li>Один</li>
    <li>Два</li>
    <li>Три</li>
    <li>Четыре</li>
    <li>Пять</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1 style="margin-top:20px">Заголовок не двигать</h1>
```

Comment: наверно фон какой то надо ...

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский в условиях про это не сказано.

Comment: это же и без условий видно - что выпадашка не видна вообще при наложении ...хотя ваше дело

Comment: вот о чем речь...)))

Comment: @Air и не говори... )))